# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'query'

Tags: python, list, fastapi, attributeerror

I have this error in my code:

```
"todo_model = db.query(modelsA.Todos).filter(modelsA.Todos.id == user_id).first()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'query'"
```

When I try it in the FastAPI Swagger, I have the error 500 Internal Server Error.

And my function looks like:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, HTTPException
import modelsA
from databaseA import engine, SessionLocal
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from schemasA import Todo

app = FastAPI()

modelsA.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


def get_db():
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

def exceptions():
    return HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Todo not found")


@app.get("/get_todo/{user_id}")
async def get_todo_id(user_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    todo_model = db.query(modelsA.Todos).filter(modelsA.Todos.id == user_id).first()
    if todo_model is not None:
        return todo_model
    raise exceptions()
```

Comment: whats the output if you change it to `db.query(modelsA).filter(modelsA.Todos.id == user_id).first()`

Comment: doesn't the error just mean that `list.query()` is not possible? Python is great for telling you what went wrong, so what it seems to be saying is that `db` is a `list`, and `query()` just doesn't exist for it. From my understanding, it would be like doing `i = 0` then `i.increment(20)`. It shows a similar error.

Comment: What is the definition of your `SessionLocal` function?